# How to mock Eventlog with WebApplicationFactory

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, integration-testing, microsoft-extensions-logging

I have a application with a Log4net RollingFileAppender for info-logs and a EventLog for error-logs

```
        builder.ClearProviders()
            .AddEventLog(new EventLogSettings { SourceName = "ABC"})
            .AddLog4Net();
```

Configured in appsettings here

```
"Logging": {
        "EventLog": {
            "LogLevel": {
                "Default": "Error"
            }
        },
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "None",
            "MyNamespace.*": "Information"
        }
    }
```

When create a WebApplicationFactory in my test suite, I substitute the logger to an in-memory implantation with this code

```
  builder.ConfigureLogging(logging =>
  {
    logging.ClearProviders();
    logging.AddProvider(_inMemLoggerProvider);
  });
```

The InMemLoggerProvider is inspired by this code https://github.com/horsdal/InMemoryLogger

When running the test-suite all errors logged from MyNamespace is caught by the InMemoryLogger.

But errors logged **from other namespaces** is **not** caught by the InMemoryLogger.

When running the application without substituting the logger, errors are logged fine to the Event Log.

Comment: what is the actual question?

Comment: When overriding the logger in my test suite, why can't I see errors logged from another namespace than MyNamespace?